# how can i remove the file from heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

```
heroku rake db:migrate
==  AddFilesizeToPapclip: migrating ===========================================
-- add_column(:papclips, :files_file_size, :string)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "files_file_size" of relation "papclips" already exists
```

then how can i rectify this error?
Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddFilesizeToPapclip` migration tries to add a database column `files_file_size` that already exists in table `papclips`.

If you want to manually remove this column, try this:

Open a Rails console on your Heroku app: `heroku run console`
Then run this code: `ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_column :papclips, :files_file_size`